# Easy bound involving logs and binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics, information-theory

I am currently working on an information theory problem where I have to bound the divergence between two distributions.

The divergence can be simplified to:

$$\sum_{k=0}^N \ {N\choose k} x^k(1-x)^{N-k} \Big[ \log( x^k(1-x)^{N-k})+\log(N+1)+\log{N\choose k} \Big]$$

where $x \in [0,1]$

And I have to show that this expression is less than $\log(N+1).$

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: Are $n$ and $N$ supposed to be the same?

Comment: Is the $n$ in the binomial coefficient intended to be $N$?

Comment: Oh,  your comment just showed up for me,  @Byron Schmuland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming $n = N$.
Essentially, you need to show that
$$S = \sum_{k=0}^{N} \dbinom{N}k x^k (1-x)^{N-k} \log\left(\dbinom{N}k x^k (1-x)^{N-k}\right) \leq 0$$
Now for $x \in (0,1)$, we always have
$$\dbinom{N}k x^k (1-x)^{N-k} < 1$$ since the sum over $k$ of these add upto one and each term is positive. Hence, we have
$$\log\left(\dbinom{N}k x^k (1-x)^{N-k}\right) < 0$$
Hence, each term in the summation of $S$ is negative and hence $S$ is negative.